# jQueryUI Draggable: Error with dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, draggable

I've slightly extended the jQueryUI example "Draggable + Sortable" ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/sortable.html ) to make it able to add draggable elements dynamically. Live example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/MLSqa .

After click the Add button the new draggable item gracefully added to the #sortable list.

But. When try to move it by mouse (1st time) it suddenly jumps to the top-left corner. And only 2nd attempt to move it gets success.

How to fix such strange behavior? How to drag the newly added item correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the update: http://jsfiddle.net/MLSqa/1/

You don't have to 'recreate' a draggable on the new item. Just add the new item to the already existing draggable.

*I also removed the $ in front of the variable box. You can put this back if you want to.*

Comment: Brilliant! Exactly what I looked for! How can I vote for you?

Comment: You can copy and paste it from the Fiddle (link in answer). How you are going to implement it I cannot tell you exactly, but the HTML code (upper left area) should be modified/inserted at the point where you want to have the draggable list. The javascript at lower left should be within a `<script>` tag or js file (included). The CSS (upper right) should be in the `<style>` tag or in a css file (included).